# pass variable to new HTML with window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im opening html file from js function:

```
function initCategoryPage(url){
    var catUrl=url;
    window.open("category.html");
}
```

I putted this script in "category.html" but it doesnt get the var catUrl:

```
<script>
    myUrl = window.opener.catUrl;
    alert(myUrl)
    id=1;
    firstTime=true;
    ArticlesBlock(); 
</script>
```

how can I pass it to category.html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it can not read it is because the variable is not global. The scope is limited to that method.

```
function initCategoryPage(url){
    window.catUrl=url;  /*make it global*/
    window.open("category.html");
}
```

A better solution would be to pass it as a querystring or use postMessage to get the value.